Spark: cast timeStamp with date and time to DateType
Given the dateTime-value:
2021-02-12T16:21:22

I tried to cast it to DateType as following:
    to_date(to_timestamp(col("Date"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd")
                .cast(DateType)

But the function returns value with date and time in its original view:
 2022-02-01T16:21:22

instead of expected:
 2022-02-01

More over, printSchema() show me, that type did not changed :
   |-- Date: string (nullable = true)

What am I doing wrong ?

It worked for me, can you add the whole code where you're adding the column?

After additional research I found, that problem not in Date formatting and casting code.  Problem is in Type erasure after Spark Union operation. But it is a matter for other question.

You don't need to cast once you've already used to_date
This should work:
.withColumn("asDate", to_date(to_timestamp(col("Date"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))

Or the one you added in the question
.withColumn("asDate", to_date(to_timestamp(col("Date"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd").cast(DateType))

If you're trying to change the original dataframe, it won't be possible without reassigning
df=df.withColumn("Date", to_date(to_timestamp(col("Date"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))

This will give the expected result.
Input:
+-------------------+
|               Date|
+-------------------+
|2021-02-12T16:21:22|
+-------------------+

Output:
+-------------------+----------+
|               Date|    asDate|
+-------------------+----------+
|2021-02-12T16:21:22|2021-02-12|
+-------------------+----------+

root
 |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- asDate: date (nullable = true)


After additional research I found, that problem not in Date formatting and casting code.  Problem is in Type erasure after Spark Union operation. But it is a matter for other question.
Also I found more simple way for Date cast:     to_date(col("Date"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").cast(DateType)
